# Check selected image dimenions and alert if out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that displays a selected image along with the image width and height. I would like to put in a check to alert if the image dimensions are greater that 390x390. I have marked the place I think a size check should go, I may be wrong. But it does not work anyway.

If someone has time you they please take a look to see how I should be dong the size check.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

My script:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var elBrowse = document.getElementById("image_field"),
elPreview = document.getElementById("preview2"),
useBlob = false && window.URL; // `true` to use Blob instead of Data-URL

function readImage (file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener("load", function () {
      var imageInfo = '<br><br>Your selected file size is<br>  Display width ' +
      image.width + ', Display height ' + 
      image.height + ' ' + '';


      elPreview.appendChild( this );
      elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",  imageInfo +'<br>');
    });
    image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
    if (useBlob) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file); 
    }
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var files = this.files;
  var errors = "";
  if (!files) {
    errors += "File upload not supported by your browser.";
  }
  if (files && files[0]) {
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      if ( (/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name) ) {
        readImage( file );
      } else {
        errors += file.name +" Unsupported Image extension\n";  
      }

      // SOMETHING LIKE THIS 
      if( (image.width < 390 && image.height < 390) .test(file.name) ) {

        readImage( file ); 
      } else {
        errors += file.name +" Selected image is to small\n";  
      }
      // END
    }
  }
  if (errors) {
    alert(errors); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you need to move the checking to the event listener because that's the first place where you can know the image resolution
here you don't have the errors list, so you need to modify it a bit yet, but you can start from here:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var elBrowse = document.getElementById("image_field"),
elPreview = document.getElementById("preview2"),
useBlob = false && window.URL; // `true` to use Blob instead of Data-URL

function readImage (file) {

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var image = new Image();

    image.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if(image.width <= 390 && image.height <= 390)
        {
        var imageInfo = '<br><br>Your selected file size is<br>  Display width ' +
        image.width + ', Display height ' + 
        image.height + ' ' + '';


        elPreview.appendChild( this );
        elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",  imageInfo +'<br>');
        } else {
             alert ( file.name +" Selected image is to big\n");  
        }
    });
    image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
    if (useBlob) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file); 
    }
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

elPreview.addEventListener("change", function() {
var files  = this.files;
var errors = "";
if (!files) {
  errors += "File upload not supported by your browser.";
}
if (files && files[0]) {
  for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  if ( (/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name) ) {

        readImage( file ); 

  } else {
    errors += file.name +" Unsupported Image extension\n";  
  }

  }
}
if (errors) {
 alert(errors); 
}
});
```

for the file variable (on the first place you aimed to check the dimensions, you can only base your condition on the file size - in bytes)

Comment: Hi again, I think this is what I needed. Many thanks for your time. [Resolved]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but did you mean something like this?

```
elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function() {
var files  = this.files;
var errors = "";
if (!files) {
  errors += "File upload not supported by your browser.";
}
if (files && files[0]) {
  for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  if ( (/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name) ) {
    if(image.width <= 390 && image.height <= 390)
    {
        readImage( file ); 
    } else {
        errors += file.name +" Selected image is to big\n";  
    }
  } else {
    errors += file.name +" Unsupported Image extension\n";  
  }

  }
}
if (errors) {
 alert(errors); 
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, that's the way I tried but when run the alert is not triggered or displayed. But thanks for looking at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the image and getting the dimension is async, so you can't use the check inside the for loop, it has do be done inside the callback 

(unless you are using async/await or generators+yield)

```js
var elBrowse = document.getElementById('image_field')
var elPreview = document.getElementById('preview2')

// No point in addthing the listener if we can't read them anyway
if ('files' in elBrowse) {
  // No need for addEventListener if you only going to have 1 listener
  elBrowse.onchange = () => {
    for (let file of elBrowse.files) {
      file.image().then(image => {
        
        // Now if you don't like the extension you can always transform it
        // using the canvas element...

        if (image.width < 390 && image.height < 390)
          return console.error(file.name + ' is to small\n')

        let info = `<br><br>${file.name} size is ${file.size} bytes
        and dimension is ${image.width}x${image.height}<br>`

        elPreview.appendChild(image)
        elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', info)

      }, err => {
        console.error(file.name + " Isn't an image")
      })
    }
  }
} else {
  console.info('reading the file is not possible, use flash alternetive?')
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Getting a bit of help from Screw-FileReader
ref: https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader
-->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader/master/index.js"></script>

<!-- 
use the accept attribute to say that you only want images
So you don't have to check for it in your code
But for just in case we listen for image.onerror when we load the image 
-->
<input id=image_field type=file multiple accept="image/*">

<div id=preview2>
```